# How to force Chrome to save passwords on self-signed or broken SSL?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, password-management

I have searched for a way to do this and never found a good answer, though there have been tickets created in the past ([#142818](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142818) & [#405549](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=412827#c54)).

Apparently, the chromium devs never created a **chrome://flags** override for "broken" SSL with password saving. This would seem to be the easiest way to fix this annoying "feature" (via flags). I DO understand completely why they block it by default.

Since there is no override to my knowledge, I had assumed that you would need to import the given self-signed certificate to a trusted root area in (Windows) store. This does not appear to work either.

Has anyone been able to get this to work? I can live with the warning - just not the lack of password saving. I spend most of my workday in a dev environment and need to keep re-entering passwords dozens of times a day (copy/paste).

EDIT (20 Feb 2023)
Please note Firefox DOES save and offer a password once you get past the warning/exempt site page. This Question is strictly in regards to Chrome. There is still no way to allow this similar to Firefox as far as I know (via flags or an exempt sites 'list').

Comment: Importing your self-signed cert into the Windows certificate store does work for Chrome, I do this all time.  How are you importing it and into which store?

Comment: Last attempt - Import self-signed .cer format into "Trusted Root Cert Auths./Certificates"

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but wouldn't be a bit easier if Chrome just added a flag override for us? Anyway, if you can point me in right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong please do :)

Comment: Importing your self-signed cert into the Windows certificate store does not work for me, too

Comment: __Update__ - I have never found an easy way/flag to do this as of date of this comment. But, with advent of free certificate issuance (LetsEncrypt/etc), my password saving problem's have been slowly going away as most times I can just create a legitimate SSL certificate. Problem solved. Note: The web server (during cert issuance) and client browser needs access to Internet, though. Which usually isn't an issue..

Comment: It appears many of the responses people are giving are misunderstanding the question because they see the word self-signed and appear to be thinking that self-signed certs mean sites owned by the OP. This question is actually asking about viewing sites on the net that have self-signed or broken certs, not the user's own site only on localhost.

Comment: @JeffClayton - Actually, both. No CA/Internet local-only loading, Expired, Self-signed, or even a bad host / localhost / IP only - it shouldn't matter. Bottom line is Firefox allows you to save a password for exempted SSL sites (See FFox settings/security/certificates/view certs/servers). Chrome still does not allow this (afaik). To test this exempt list, use Firefox at (https) self-signed.badssl.com, expired.badssl.com, local self-signed site that uses passwords, etc.

Comment: They have different methods of resolution though. It seems only a third-party management program would be the solution that would cover both, and not require server access.

Comment: It might be worth trying Bitwarden. It has a very good rating, free for personal use & multi-platform.

Comment: There are others too, but I mentioned it because that one is a free option.

Answer (score 39):

I did not know about this option before today, but it appears that Chrome does have a flag for allowing insecure certificates from the `localhost` origin.  This option is available from the `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` page:

[image: Screenshot]

This will only help you for self-signed certificates on the `localhost` origin, and I have not tested it to see if it actually fixes your problem with the password manager, but it looks promising.

Comment: @bshea, FYI hovering over the  "answered XX minutes/hours/days ago" label will display and exact timestamp.

Comment: I wish chrome flags would support a complete override on cert checks (or specifically password saving from non-localhost source). There is a nice warning about using flags.. so I don't see why they don't. Liability i guess.

Comment: @bshea, yeah I think they're trying to be security conscious.  If the flag is there, then lazy website owners or malicious actors may instruct users to go flip the flag to enable their bad practices.  If the flag is not there, there is no bypass

Comment: This didn't work for me. What worked for me was to generate a self-signed certificate and adding it to the system truststore as always trusted.

Comment: Anyone with a solution for Chrome in mac. Nothing has worked yet for me for self-signed certificates in localhost.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It works on localhost but not with expired certificates on the internet.

Comment: @Bachsau You are correct - removed as "answered". Question should reappear on 'unanswered' now. (But, this is still a decent answer for a local host origin).

Answer (score 19):

Alternatively, you can start Chrome with a command line switch `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com"` or go to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and enter your unsafe origin, e.g. `http://example.com`.

Comment: Nice. Hadn't seen that flag/switch before. Can you also save a password for that 'bad ssl' domain?

Comment: Didn't work for me either. I had to generate a self signed certificate and add it to system truststore

Comment: I don't think this is for SSL/TLS at all. The secure origin policy is about cross site scripting, not encryption and authentification.

Answer (score 6):

Navigate to `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`.

Then click "Enable".

Just be extremely wary that this is a major security flaw.

Edit: Linking to chrome://flags/ no longer works due to the fact that Chrome no longer allows hyperlinks to the Chrome protocol due to security regarding the use of url encoding in hyperlinks to the protocol. Certain url-encoded strings would crash older versions of Chrome. Rather than fixing this issue, they completely eliminated the option for hyperlinks. So just navigate to that location by copying and pasting the link.

Comment: That flag is news to me. Not quite what i needed (localhost only), but it will certainly help.. Thanks.

Comment: just FYI - the link doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to use macro (iMacros) instead break the security default of chrome and that's better to protect you from virus

edit:

- download [iMacros](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp) chrome extension
- install it
- create chrome new tab
- open i macros
- then move To record section and press record
- at new tab go to login page
- fill your username and password
- press login
- then stop record and save page

and voila now you can play your recorded macro in bookmark section to login effortlessly

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Could you [edit] your answer to make it clear how it is answering the question?

Comment: This appears to save the password like a password manager, but I don't think the passwords are saved in an encrypted format. While this can work, I suspect downloading a more-secure password management program might be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me, I ended up following a combination of the powershell answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27257921/264607) adding the `-NotAfter` flag as well, slightly modified to use copy and paste from comments instead of exporting the cert.  Once I had all this working for the correct domains, chrome stopped saying the cert was invalid and prompted to save password.

> **To Create the new certificate for your specific domain:**
>
> Open Powershell ISE as admin, run the command:
>
> ```
> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName *.mydomain.com, localhost -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
> ```
>
> **To trust the new certificate:**
>
> - Open mmc.exe
> - Go to Console Root -> Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal
> - Select the certificate you have created, copy
> - Go to Console Root -> Certificates -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities, paste
>
> **To bind the certificate to your site:**
>
> - Open IIS Manager
> - Select your site and choose Edit Site -> Bindings in the right pane
> - Add new https binding with the correct hostname and the new certificate

Comment: creating a new ceritifcate is no solution when someone asks how to solve it on the client. Manys times people dont have access to the server, but need to use internal services with no proper ssl cert for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

chrome://flags/#legacy-tls-enforced

Whit this chrome flag set to disabled chrome ignore security enforcement and enable password manager on tls 1.0 sites too.

Comment: This answer could really use some explanation.

Comment: While this does indeed allow login to sites with self-signed certs, without going through the annoying "yeah, yeah I know I'm going to an unsecured page" page - but in my tests, it does not allow passwords on those sites to be saved.

Comment: legacy-tls-enforced is no longer a flag in chrome (using version 121)