# Chrome is not offering to save passwords in a website with a self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I used [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1241235/350002) but still unable to save passwords with Chrome.

Comment: Duplicate of [Chrome - Password saving with self-signed or broken SSL](https://superuser.com/questions/1241132/chrome-password-saving-with-self-signed-or-broken-ssl)