# How can I manually add a password to Chrome password manager?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management

How do I manually add a password to Chrome? For some reason, it doesn't ask me if I want to save my password for a website after I log in. I think I answered `No` the first time that it asked me, and now it's become a pain in the neck.

Comment: See if this helps>>>>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917140/chrome-password-manager-how-to-add-password-manually

Comment: Go to Chrome, Settings, scroll down for Passwords.  See if your site above is in the list and delete the entry (... more)

Comment: Were you able to try this?  Once deleted, of course you can r-add it in the normal way.

Comment: @John, some web sites have a forwarding step in them, so after you enter your password, the page that comes up forwards to another page immediately, and then the Chrome password save never shows up. So your recommendation works _often_, but not always.

Comment: Chrome has its own credential manager (does not use Windows), so you may need to live with the current situation or use a third party password manager as suggested in the answer provided here. I have one or two (of many) in Edge that do the same thing.

Comment: @Moab I can't see `PasswordImport` as explained in that answer. And searching for `password import` in experimental features, returns no results.

Comment: @John the site is not in the list.

Comment: The answer provided was essentially suggesting to google for a third party tool to add a Chrome password. I do not know of such a site myself. I was thinking that if you deleted the Chrome entry for the problem site, you could go back and Chrome should again ask you for the password for the site

Comment: @John I mean, the entry of that site is not in Chrome's `Never Saved`

Comment: There is a link in the post above mine, and my post was about using Chrome itself.

Comment: Not saying you need to do this, but ever since I switched to KeePass I've not had these weird problems related to Chrome or any other browser. Also made it easier to switch between browsers and use multiple browsers without requiring the use of one specific browser's password manager. I am using the Kee extension for Chrome/Edge/Firefox to read that database for passwords and it works much better than Chrome's password manager functioned.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to save a password from a page where there is no password input field, you can simply add a password input field anywhere on the page and start writing into that field. Google Chrome then adds a small key icon into the navigation bar which allows you to store the password onto that domain.

#### How to add a password-input field into the page with the Chrome DevTools

1. Go to your desired web site.
2. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on your keyboard to open the Google Chrome DevTools or right click on an element and click on `Inspect`.
3. Select the tab `Elements`.
4. Select any (small) HTML tag and hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit it (or double-click).
5. Append the following element: `<input type="password">`.
6. Click on another HTML tag to save it.
7. Enter some password into the newly created input field on the website.

Comment: This worked for me, I added `<form><input type="password"><input type="submit"></form>` I cannot believe that this is necessary. Why can we not add passwords manually. Like storing a password for something other than a website.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The place where I want Chrome to save a password and it is not saving it, is already an `<input type="password">` element.

Comment: @MartinArgerami And you don't see the little key icon in the navbar on the right side?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3: nope, it's not there. It does appear in all other websites where I log in, but not in this one. The only thing that maybe makes a difference is that it is my router's page, so the address is local and the certificate invalid; could that prevent the mechanism from working? But now that I think about it, Chrome did save the password with my previous router.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Chrome does not allow passwords to be saved from insecure websites. See e.g. https://superuser.com/q/1241132/515892 to circumvent that behavior.

Comment: this works and a plus is that you can also use a faek website like my-bank-secret-pin.fakedomain edit page to add input, compile input and click on key icon on address url and save password and user

Answer (score 17):

At the moment there is a beta-feature which can be activated on the following chrome settings page: `chrome://flags/#password-import`

[image: Import Passwords]

It can be used to import a list of passwords.

Furthermore, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917140/chrome-password-manager-how-to-add-password-manually) also on another question.

Comment: This should be the answer, it also nicely bypasses the flag that stops Chrome to offer to save passwords ;)

Answer (score 12):

This is now available in the latest Chrome release

- Open Chrome browser
- Visit `chrome://settings/passwords`
- Click `Add` button that appears next to `Saved Passwords`
  add password manually to Chrome via its settings
- In the Add password dialog, type site URL, username, and Password in respective fields and click Save.

**Note:** The feature is enabled by default in Chrome version 100. Here is how you can enable it Chrome 98 or Chrome 99 versions

- Head to `chrome://flags`
- Search for “password”, in the dropdown for “Add Passwords in Settings”, select `Enabled`
- Add passwords in Settings flag Chrome
- Restart the browser.

Source: [Chrome is making it easier to add passwords manually](https://techdows.com/2022/01/chrome-add-password-manually.html)

Comment: Very good! My chrome version was 100 but i didn't see the [Add] button in settings page! It seems that when your browser is auto updated from older versions to 100, it is not shown by default and you have to go to `chrome://flags` and set `Add Passwords in Settings` to `Enabled` as you noted.

Answer (score 10):

As stated here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PasswordCredential:

```javascript
const cred = new PasswordCredential({
  id: id,
  password: password,
  name: name,
});

navigator.credentials.store(cred)
 .then(()  => {
   // Do something
 });
```

Comment: Great answer. Note that you must replace "id", "password" and "name" with the name of the service, login and password.


Then this piece of code must be pasted into the Chrome/Firefox console

Answer (score 4):

The most manual way without having google chrome installed, without any tools besides a text editor.
Open your text editor.
type

```
url,username,password
https://example.org,username,password
```

save this file with .csv extension, and then
go to password manager https://passwords.google.com/?ep=1 click on settings
[image: password import]

import your csv file. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a simple technique and it worked for the websites that never prompts you save passwords.

Go to the password setting page. follow the blue link : View and manage saved passwords in your [Google Account](https://passwords.google.com/)

Click on the password option icon at the right side of the text "Password manager" Export the password.csv file. Open it in excel. Add your website, username and password according to the existing entries in the file. save it in the same .csv format. Go to that password setting in google account again. Import the edited .csv file. Refresh the webpage.

That's it. Now browse your desired website and see the id password are auto filled in.

Thanks.

Comment: the csv is built with the comma separated values `website, url, username,password.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to add a password to Chrome without using third party software. 
If a website no longer asks you to save the password after selecting the "No" option, you can reset this choice in the settings.

To do this:

1: First open Chrome.

2: Then go in the password settings. Either copy/paste this link:

chrome://settings/passwords

Or click the three dots on the top right, and select settings in the drop down menu. Then select the first choice in the Autofill section: Passwords

3: On this page you will find a list called "Never Save". The website you cannot add will be in this list. Click on the X on the right to remove it.

4: Go back to the website you want to add a password to chrome (log off if needed) and then re-enter your credentials. Chrome will once more ask you if you want to save the password for this website.

Note: Be sure the "Offer to save passwords" choice is active in the passwords menu.

Comment: The site is not in `Never Save`. Actually that list is empty

Comment: Weird...I think the easiest way then is resetting Chrome completely. Save all your passwords and data using sync beforehand.

Comment: Would you know of a third party software that achieves that?

Comment: @Qwerty: as Chrome doesn't ask for saving the password, it might not even recognize there is a password. So even if you add it manually it might still not work.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Right...

Comment: Also, make sure that "Offer to save passwords" is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer but most seemed a bit hacky... I used this method instead, nice and easy...

1. Use the export passwords option to get the CSV template.
2. Delete everything in the CSV except the header row.
3. Add the details in the second row with the details for the password to add.
4. Import the CSV (might need to use the chrome://flags#PasswordImport flag to get the import option)

Comment: Thanks Simon - the link for setting the Import flag did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the passwords by pressing the view button near the link and change it.
Here is the pic for it below:

[image: Here is the pic for it below.]

After that, you may change the password.

Comment: The question about adding a password - so there is nothing to change.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this actually works on all the things. I stumbled across this by trial and error. I had a site that I signed up for under an alternate account, but wanted to access using my main account and save the PW/Username for.

1. Logout
2. Go to site's login form
3. When Chrome/Google offers a suggested password, select that. This will add an entry to your passwords (although the incorrect password obviously.)
4. Go to your google account to manage passwords.
5. Search for and update to use the correct password.

Completely "manual" but works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Offer to save passwords* is enabled when you browse to `chorme://settings/passwords`

I had the same problem where I was not being prompted to save my username/password for an internal company website. Then I realized that the browser was indicating the website certificate was invalid. Because this was an internal company website that I knew I could trust; I imported the certificate into *Keychain Access*, set trust to *Allow Always* and I was back in business!!

Chrome on Mac

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Feel free to remove the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that Chrome for Windows wouldn't offer to save a password, but Chrome for iOS did. So that may be a simple solution for some.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In a text editor (NotePad for example) create a two line text file with commas after first two entries on each line. First line URL,username,password. Next line fill in your values. Save it on your desktop with extension .csv You can also do it by putting these values into an Excel sheet and saving as .csv format.

Example:

URL,username,password

https://www.MyWebsite.com,QueenOfTheUniverse,NotGonnaTellIt2U!@!

In Google Password Manager (passwords.google.com) click the gear symbol in the upper right.

Click "Import Passwords" then select the .csv file you just saved.

That should work.

Don't forget to overwrite your .csv file with junk before saving then deleting it.